# What is $emit(\'remove\') in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I want to make some list item from array and want delete them when i click each list item.When i click each item each item get deleted but here $emit(\'remove\') is actually what in vue js plaese help.

```
<button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">X</button>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very descriptive, please include an example (codepen would be great) or explain it better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems it connected to emit event which is bind to that element.

```
<button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">X</button>
```

is connected to this piece of code in the declaration, you can see this code is just above in your example

```
<li
  is="todo-item"
  v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
  v-bind:title="todo"
  v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)"
></li>
```

here you can see:

```
v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)"
```

this is the event so when you click on that button this will be fired and that item will be removed from the list.

and make sure this list items are component so it use that template to render each items.

if you have further question please feel free to ask.

Comment: I know how it works, i just wanted to know what is $emit  in vuejs and syntax of it.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-emit  --  you can see its syntax here.
its used to trigger events .. here we have created "remove" event it is triggring that event on that instance.
so in our case this will fire this code : "todos.splice(index, 1)" which is written for that event.